# how can i pass string(taken as input from user) to a pointer function in c?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void add(int a,int b)
{
    int c=a+b;
    printf("\nSum=%d",c);
}
void hello(char *name)
{
    printf("Hello %s",*name);
}
int main()
{
    int  a,b;
    char name[20];
    void (*ptr)(int,int)=&add;
    void (*hello)(char*)=hello;
    printf("Enter your Name:");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    hello(&name);
    printf("Enter the two values\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    ptr(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

i want to take input from user then pass it to function but i am unable to do so.

Here is what my complier shows as error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVYL6.png

Comment: Add compiler error as text pls...

Comment: A) you declare `void (*hello)(char*)` of name `hello` and then assign it the value of `hello`. B) you are referencing `name` which already is of type c-string (`char*`), just pass it to `scanf`/`printf`. C) you most likely want to print the string, not just the first character in the function `hello`

Comment: Is there any specific reason for complicating otherwise trivial code with all those function pointers?

Comment: @gkhaos  20 16  [Error] cannot convert 'char ( * )[20]' to 'char *' in argument passing

Comment: @HarryK. yeah,i am asked solve using pointer function

Comment: @YogeshSatyam, in that case @MrBen's edited reply below should do for starters, but add a check against overflowing `name` on input (probably adding a limiting regex in `scanf` or replace it completely with  `fgets` or a custom func of your own) .

Comment: Here's a good old link for reading stdin: http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html

Comment: Give your function pointers different names so that they do not clash with the names of actual functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to access the array address, it will be implicitly converted to `char*` when you pass it to the functions (both to `scanf` and `hello`).

I don't see the use of the functions pointers, so in order to simplify the code, I would rewrite it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Sum = %d\n", a + b);
}

void hello(char *name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\n", name);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    char name[20];

    printf("Enter your Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    hello(name);

    printf("Enter the two values\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a ,&b);
    add(a, b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you insist of using the pointers, this is how main should be written:

```
int main()
{
    int  a = 0, b = 0;
    char name[20];

    void (*add_ptr)(int, int) = &add;
    void (*hello_ptr)(char *) = &hello;

    printf("Enter your Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    hello_ptr(name);

    printf("Enter the two values\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    add_ptr(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i know this but i asked use pointer funtion to solve